# how to manipulate vue-bootstrap-table by wenzhixin

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-table

I just wanna ask questions on how to manipulate further the vue-bootstrap-table by wenzhixin

so far here is my vue-bootstrap-table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGDpZ.png

here are my questions:

how can I reorder my fixed toolbar? according to the screenshot above, can I move the trash button after the advanced search button?.

In advanced search modal, how to manipulate the textboxes and change into datepicker?
here is an image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLjkZ.png

How can I make the row datas in First Name column(referring to the screenshot table) into a link?